# How do i make the image fit to the pdf page with no border using iText? image.jpg

Tags: itext

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(picture.jpg);
image.scaleAbsolute(800f, 600f); // i just set the image by a certain size
document.add(image);
```

I want it fits to the whole page of pdf. What method can i use? i need help, thank you

Comment: You use `document.add(image)`. Thus, your image is given to iText automatized layout'ing routines. These routines attempt to respect the margin you either explicitly have set or which are at their default values. Unless the margins all are 0, your image won't fit the whole page. Thus, either work on a page at the time of creation of which the margins have been set to 0, or use `PdfWriter.getDirectContent` to add your image directly to the page content, not via iText automatized layout'ing routines.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution, thank your for your question and the comment of @mkl.
here is the sample code, I hope this might help someone.

```
int width =x; int height = y; 
//define these two based on your required width and height ratio of image

document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(width, height));
document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

img.scaleToFit(height, width);
```